# Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 Upgrade Boots Oddly

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, boot-repair

After allowing Ubuntu to upgrade itself a while back, it seems to get stuck while booting. It alternates between a black screen, then a white screen with the cursor, then back to the black screen over and over. I've read all the other posts here and elsewhere that seem to point to NVidia but I don't have NVidia.

Holding Shift while booting and selecting Advanced options for Ubuntu, then selecting Recovery Mode, when I select the Resume Normal Boot choice from the Recovery Menu, it boots as it should. Any ideas how to fix it short of a fresh install?

Comment: So is you observe the grub menu carefully, the version have become 2, so your system boots with the first one which seems not to work well. So the recovery and resume normal boot uses the older grub and it works. Your job is to find out how to remove the newer grub and rely on the older one then gently do dist-upgrade or upgrade... I had same issue... Or optionally choose the boot image from the boot options and choose the older version...

Comment: As far as I know, it was using Grub2 for some time but good idea and makes sense. Not sure how to proceed as I'm a GUI person but will research. I did already try the Update grub bootloader option already but it made no difference. One thing that fails to start is something called LSB GNUstep distributed object mapper but not sure what that is although it doesn't appear to be related to booting.

Comment: I tried uninstalling Grub, then installing the old Grub but no candidate could be found. Reinstalling Grub2, I see that it's a Beta version: 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu so is there a way to install a NON-beta version?